# android : Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. v is missing it

Tags: android, data-binding

I am getting this error when i add `android:onClick="@{(v) v.requestFocus()` to a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:onClick="@{(v) v.requestFocus()}">
```

Comment: normally we are passing view onClick method name  in android:onClick="" , is it possible to pass java code on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "->" in your lambda:

```
android:onClick="@{(v) -> v.requestFocus()}">
```